# spring controller - returning a map instead of creating a separate object

Tags: java, spring

From your point of view, what is the best way to return a simple object from a Spring REST Controller?

One way would be to create an object

```
@RestController
public MyObj x(){...}

class MyObj {
  String a;
  List<String> bList;
}
```

If you have multiple objects of this kind you will end up with many separate files for each object.

Another way would be to use a map

```
@RestController
public Map<String, List<String>>x(){
     return service...dao.getInfo();
}

public Map<String, List<String>> dao.getInfo() {...}
```

This is a bit harder to read and you need to get to the DAO to see what it returns. It needs a very good documentation.

Is there any other way to obtain a similar behavior?

Is map a good way of solving this problem in a service architecture?

Comment: return `ResponseEntity` using `Iterateable` ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the the best way to do that, is to create a generic object RestResponse which includes the generic as payload. Then have a factory that is able to create the correct response for your payload.

RestResponse:

```
public class RestResponse<T> {
    private int responseCode;
    private T payload;

    public RestResponse() {
    }

    public RestResponse(int responseCode) {
        this.responseCode = responseCode;
    }

    public T getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    public void setPayload(T payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }
}
```

Factory:

```
@Component
public class RestResponseFactory {
    public <T> ResponseEntity<RestResponse<T>> newRestResponse(HttpStatus status) {
        return newRestResponse(null, status);
    }

    public <T> ResponseEntity<RestResponse<T>> newRestResponse(T resource, HttpStatus status) {
        RestResponse<T> response = new RestResponse<T>();
        response.setResponseCode(status.value());
        response.setPayload(resource);
        return new ResponseEntity<RestResponse<T>>(response, status);
    }
}
```

Then in your Rest controller you should be able to use the factory to generate the payload.

```
ResponseEntity<RestResponse<MyRessource>> response =
    responseFactory.newRestResponse(new MyRessource("SomeData"), HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

This will allow you to generate responses with arbitrary objects with the following controller:

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MyRessourceController {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/dosomething", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity<RestResponse<MyRessource>> dosomething() {

        ResponseEntity<RestResponse<MyRessource>> response =
                responseFactory.newRestResponse(new MyRessource("SomeData"), HttpStatus.CREATED);


        return response;
    }

}
```